# How can I check if an object is returned from a filter call?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to return true or false, but the filter method returns a new array with the object that matches the return.  Is it possible to just return true?  I have looked at the includes prototype but that seems to return the entire object as well.

I have tried the following...

```
let check = this.props.data.filter(obj => {
  return obj.idNum.includes(value);
});

let check = this.props.data.map(obj => {
  return obj.idNum.includes(value);
});

let check = this.props.data.filter(obj => {
  return obj.idNum.includes(value) : true ? false;
});
```

I'm really just trying to make check true if the array of objects contains the value I'm looking for.  I'm checking the idNum for each object for a match.

Comment: have a look at [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: In addition to JanS's suggestion (which is the best way), `filter` will aways return an array, you can check the length property which will be falsey if zero or truthy for anything else: `let found = arr.filter(someFilterFn).length`.

Comment: some prototype is returning true for any match.  So if my ID is 00010 it returns true on 0, 00, 000, 0001, 02001, 01230  -  I'm looking for an exact match

Comment: Uhm, by the way, your last try isn't syntactically correct. The ternary operator should look like `obj.idNum.includes(value) ? true : false`. Additionally, it doesn't provide any logic and can absolutely be omitted in this case.

Comment: oh yes - that was a typo sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the array `.some` method. You could use it like so:

```
let check = this.props.data.some(obj => {
    return obj.idNum === value;
});
```

The some method returns true if the function given to it returns true for any of the array elements.

Comment: I tried that.  Let's say the ID is 000020 - the above method returns true for 0, 00, 000, 0002, 00001, 001010, etc...

Comment: @user3622460 Your ID's are strings right? If so, don't use the includes, and just compare directly. EG: `return obj.idNum === value`. I'll edit my answer.